# Largest number of times that a bit of fuel has been exchanged between spacecraft? Between spacecraft tanks?

Tags: record, refueling

Scott Manley's [Russia's New Space Station Module Causes Alarm On ISS](https://youtu.be/jTR5evpFLb4?t=818) says a bit after `18:38`:

> The fuel system isn’t going to be entirely isolated because when Progress docks to Nauka, they have to be able to take propellant from the Progress and feed that into the main tanks on the space station for refueling.

which reminds us that fuels are regularly passed back and forth between spacecraft at the ISS.

But I wonder what the record is for the number of fuel transfers between spacecraft, and between spacecraft tanks.

**Question:** Largest number of times that a bit of fuel has been exchanged between spacecraft? Between spacecraft tanks?

Not restricted to ISS.

Comment: Largest number of times that a bit of fuel has been exchanged? That suggests fuel going back and forth? AFAIK only DARPA's Boeing ASTRO/NextSat Orbital Express demonstration did that.  Transferring approximately 31.97 lbm of hydrazine to NextSat,  then transferred from NextSat back to ASTRO. Otherwise normal refueling and the Robotic transfer experiment on the ISS all seemed to be one-way refueling jobs. ATV and Progress transferred the same amount of fuel for refueling, 850kg.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby no my question doesn't necessarily suggest that exchanged back and forth is the only possibility. But if you have a convincing argument to that effect please write it up as an answer!

Comment: Progress has been refueling Salyut, MIr, and ISS stations for decades now.  If you count every Progress refueling that is a LOT over the decades.

Comment: yup. there's even a version of Progress with larger capacity but if it was filled to capacity (of fuel) i don't know, due to obvious launcher restrictions/parameters.