# Which two spacecraft are being shown disconnecting here, and what was the connection for?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object, refueling

The new Wall Street Journal video [China's Answer to the Aging International Space Station: The Tech Behind Tiangong | WSJ](https://youtu.be/m8qxSfdPBSY?t=253) shows *what looks like it might be* a fuel transfer connection decoupling at `04:14`. It's a little scary because after they disconnect the fittings appear to bump and grind a bit, rather than cleanly separate with linear motion.

**Question:** Which two spacecraft are being shown disconnecting here, and what was the connection for?

"bonus points" for any information on this particular event in the footage; was it sub-optimal? Was anything damaged?

[image: screen shot from Wall Street Journal video *China's Answer to the Aging International Space Station: The Tech Behind Tiangong | WSJ] [image: screen shot from Wall Street Journal video *China's Answer to the Aging International Space Station: The Tech Behind Tiangong | WSJ]

Comment: tangentially related: [Largest number of times that a bit of fuel has been exchanged between spacecraft? Between spacecraft tanks?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54573/12102)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a demonstration program for robotic refueling that took place on ISS with [Dextre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextre) in 2013.  This was the [Robotic Refueling Mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_Refueling_Mission) (RMM).

A nasa page with several videos is at https://nexis.gsfc.nasa.gov/rrm_refueling_task-blog.html

So it's not two separate spacecraft.  It's Dextre and an experimental device on the ISS.